# How do I use the belt on a jeans or a pant such that the button is not visibly suspended

Tags: clothing

[image]
Because the pant is a bit bigger in size and I'd like to tighten it a bit, what happens as a result is that the button gets suspended and visible. I do not want to use suspenders because it is not in fashion in my geography, so looking forward to some advice on this.

Comment: Put a tuck in the back (off centre so it's not against your spine) to take up the slack.

Comment: What is the belt looped through? All my trousers/pants have a belt loop each side of, and close to the buckle.

Comment: @WeatherVane there are belt loops in my pants, just that those aren't visible because of cropping

Answer (score 2):

**The Carlson-Tucker Belt Lifehack**

Try two equal half-tucks on each side of your pants waistband just in front of (or behind) the side belt loops. That should give you a trim appearance and comfortable fit.

Then, tighten your belt to hold the tucks from loosening.

Good luck.

Comment: Kind of works, but at the end of the day it's a hack and I have to tighten a bit more just to make sure that tucks do not loosen up, which is not a pleasant experience after a couple of hours.

Answer (score 1):

Make a tuck between two of the belt loops at the side of the jeans and fix those temporarily with safety pins (best those made for use for babies as those will not open during use) or with a couple of stitches with needle and yarn.

You will still need a belt as neither method look good nor is strong enough for long term use.

If you only need to take up a small bit of space, some people will make a small yarn loop, have that around the button and the tongue of the belt, which is a bit tricky to place but if you are the kind of person who only does up the belt once per day it might work for you.